# Индикатор загрузки приложения в Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

Как добавить индикатор загрузки для `QApplication`?

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  QApplication app( argc, argv );
  // старт
  ...
  mainwindow->show();
  // завершение
  int res = app.exec();
  delete mainwindow;
  return res;
}
```

Необходимо сразу после создания `app` начать отображение прогрессбар или другого индикатора загрузки, а когда цепочка действий будет выполнена и загрузится mainwindow, закончить отображение индикатора.
Пытался через `QSplashSreen`.
Пример из оф. документации

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QPixmap pixmap(":/splash.png");
     QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
     splash.show();
     app.processEvents();
     ...
     QMainWindow window;
     window.show();
     splash.finish(&window);
     return app.exec();
 }
```

Мой пример:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  QApplication app( argc, argv );
  QPixmap pixmap(":/splash.gif");
  QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
  splash.show();
  app.processEvents();
  // старт
  ...
  mainwindow->show();
  // завершение
  splash.finish(mainwindow);
  int res = app.exec();
  delete mainwindow;
  return res;
}
```

Вначале вместо `*.gif` показывается серый квадрат такого же размера, затем подгружается изображение, только когда уже открылось `mainwindow`. Анимации нет.

**Обновление**: попытки вынести в отдельный класс, наследуемый от `QSplashScreen`, либо наследуемый от `QThread` - т.е. отдельный поток - и общаться через сигнал-слот, пока закончились неудачей, эффект тот же, графика не отображается, пока не будет выполнен `app.exec()`.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Насколько можно судить по приведённому коду, Ваша "цепочка действий" выполняется в GUI-потоке. Но пока она выполняется, GUI-поток не может обрабатывать события, в том числе и события перерисовки. Выходом является  выполнение цепочки действий в отдельном потоке. После получения от него сигнала `finished`, GUI может продолжить свою работу и отобразить `MainWindow`.

Вторым вариантом решения задачи может быть вызов `QApplication::processEvents()` внутри кода инициализации. Но это некрасивое решение и есть риск появления "фризов", т.е. "замирания" графического интерфейса, если между `processEvents` проходит заметное для пользователя время.

Comment: Qt4 не допускает работу с виджетами не в главном потоке. В Qt5, вроде бы, пытались это побороть, но я не помню, чем там дело кончилось. Я бы запихал инициализацию в отдельный поток и общался с GUI через сигнал-слотовый механизм.

Comment: спасибо. Отрисовку прелоадера, получается, нужно делать в отдельном потоке? эта цепочка действий включает показ виджетов, например, диалоговых окон. с `MainWindow` эти действия никак не связаны.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, буду пробовать через сигналы-слоты.